# How to assign file content to chef node attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have `fingreprint.txt` at the location `"#{node['abc.d']}/fingreprint.txt"`

The contents of the file are as below:
`time="2015-03-25T17:53:12C" level=info msg="SHA1 Fingerprint=7F:D0:19:C5:80:42:66"`

Now I want to retrieve the value of fingerprint and assign it to chef attribute
I am using the following ruby block

```
ruby_block "retrieve_fingerprint" do  
    block do  
        path="#{node['abc.d']}/fingreprint.txt"  
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)  
        command = 'grep -Po '(?<=Fingerprint=)[^"]*' path '  
        command_out = shell_out(command)  
        node.default['fingerprint'] = command_out.stdout  
    end  
    action :create  
end
```

It seems not to be working because of missing escape chars in `command = 'grep -Po '(?<=Fingerprint=)[^"]*' path '`. 
Please let me know if there is some other way of assigning file content to node attribute

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to answer this: first I would do the read (`IO.read`) and parsing (`RegExp.new` and friends) in Ruby rather than shelling out to `grep`.

```
if IO.read("#{node['abc.d']}/fingreprint.txt") =~ /Fingerprint=([^"]+)/
  node.default['fingerprint'] = $1
end
```

Second, don't do this at all because it probably won't behave how you expect. You would have to take in to account both the two-pass loading process and the fact that default attributes are reset on every run. If you're trying to make an Ohai plugin, do that instead. If you're trying to use this data in later resources, you'll probably want to store it in a global variable and make copious use of the `lazy {}` helper.

Comment: I have never used Ohai Plugin. Please suggest how can I convert the above ruby_block into OHAI plugin. Also. with IO.read I am getting compile error becuase the file doesn't exist until run time.

Comment: You know that Google thing?